# How to calculate interpolating splines in 3D space?

Tags: 3d, interpolation, spline

I'm trying to model a smooth path between several control points in three dimensions, the problem is that there doesn't appear to be an explanation on how to use splines to achieve this. Are splines a subset of other types of curves such as Bezier curve or the Hermite curve?

I have successfully found cubic splines in 2 dimensions, but I'm not sure how to extend it into 3 dimensions and why there is no explanation about this.

Is there a better and more documented type of curve I could use to achieve this? My goal is to move an object along the smooth curve going through the control points. Please help.

Comment: [This article](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/splines.pdf) focuses on explaining the thought processes and concepts behind 2D splines, but can be extended to 3 dimensions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, let's understand **parametric** splines.

Let's assume we already know how to find $y$ as a (spline) function of $x$. And suppose we have a sequence of 2D points $P_i = (x_i,y_i)$. First, we assign a parameter value $t_i$ to each point $P_i$. The usual way to do this is to use chord-lengths -- you choose the $t_i$ values such that $t_i - t_{i-1} = \|P_i - P_{i-1}\|$. Then you compute $x$ as a function of $t$. The calculation is the one you already know, but it's just $x=f(t)$ instead of $y=f(x)$. Now do the same thing with $y$ and $t$. So, now you have both $x$ and $y$ as functions of $t$. In other words, you have a 2D point $(x,y)$ as function of $t$, which means you have a 2D parametric curve.

Now, the extension to 3D is straightforward. We just make $z$ a function of $t$, also. So, now we have $(x,y,z)$ as a function of $t$, so we have a parametric space curve.

To do 3D spline interpolation using Matlab functions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352662/3d-spline-interpolation-matlab).

A better reference is [this web site](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html).

Bezier curves are also easy to extend to 3D. As you probably know, the equation of a cubic Bezier curve is
$$
\mathbf{C}(t) = (1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0 + 
             3t(1-t)^2\mathbf{P}_1 + 
                3t^2(1-t)\mathbf{P}_2 + 
                t^3\mathbf{P}_3
$$
In this equation it doesn't matter whether the control points $\mathbf{P}_0$, $\mathbf{P}_1$, $\mathbf{P}_2$, $\mathbf{P}_3$ are 2D or 3D.

Comment: I found cubic splines in 2D by finding y in terms of x and not t, which is why I'm now confused. I can't find any decent explanation to find splines in terms of a parameter t.

Comment: The math is identical. See the additions to my answer.

Comment: @Saras take a look at this very good pdf, except for an error in computed value of the b coefficient in the 14.1 paragraph, where " = −. 7" and not "−2 ∙ (2 2⁄3)": https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/splines.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This seems relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

There is a MATLAB toolkit with this functionality (spline toolkit).

Comment: But isn't that used for images and surfaces? I only need a path.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. You want to parameterize your spline as in @bubba's solution.